# Writing a complex Java boolean expression

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code which if the following conditions are met it will say marry me otherwise it would say get lost.

Conditions which need to be met:

22 to 27 year old male, non-smoking, under 72 inches tall, under 160 pounds, good-looking, able to relocate.”

This is the code I have so far written.
However, it prints get lost even though I believe it matches the given criteria? What is wrong?

Furthermore, how can I put it in terms of a single boolean?

```
public class marry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int weight = 150;
        int age = 24;
        int height = 71;
        boolean isASmoker = false;
        boolean isMale = true;
        boolean isGoodLooking = true;
        boolean isAbleToRelocate = true;

        if (((weight < 160 && (age <= 27 && age >= 22)) && ((height < 72) && ((isASmoker = false) && (isMale = true))) && ((isGoodLooking = true) && (isAbleToRelocate = true)))) {
            System.out.println("Marry Me!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Get Lost!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: **Avoid lines longer than 80 characters.** (c) jcc

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Sorry, I will fix it right away,

Comment: You use ``=`` to compare values, you have to use ``==`` in java.

Comment: Hi @f1sh How can I use one boolean instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my little piece of code for deciding your problem:

```
class Person {
    private int weight;
    private int age;
    private int height;
    private boolean isASmoker;
    private boolean isMale;
    private boolean isGoodLooking;
    private boolean isAbleToRelocate;

    public Person(int weight, int age, int height, boolean isASmoker, boolean isMale, boolean isGoodLooking, boolean isAbleToRelocate) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.isASmoker = isASmoker;
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.isGoodLooking = isGoodLooking;
        this.isAbleToRelocate = isAbleToRelocate;
    }

    public boolean isGood() {
        return weight < 160 && age <= 27 && age >= 22 && 
               height < 72 && !isASmoker && isMale && 
               isGoodLooking && isAbleToRelocate;
               // (variable == true) => variable
               // (variable == false) => !variable
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person(150, 24, 71, false, true, true, true);
        System.out.println(person.isGood() ? "Marry Me!" : "Get Lost!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your boolean expressions are incorrect. The single "=" performs an assignment.  You need "==" for a boolean comparison.

Change

```
isASmoker = false
```

to

```
isASmoker == false
```

And

```
isMale = true
```

to

```
isMale == true
```

As for readability, this entire expression could be cleaned-up quite a bit by removing unnecessary parenthesis and changing (variable == false) to !variable.  This is somewhat a matter of preference, although I think most would agree that as written, this expression is quite long and hard to follow.

Comment: Where? in the boolean in the up of the command or at the bottom beside the other code at if @EJK

Comment: Better yet, just drop the comparison and use the boolean variables by themselves.

Comment: @EJK also how can I make all of this code into one boolean expression?

Comment: Good point.  Yes, there is lots of room to improve this conditional.

Comment: @BilltheLizard How can i drop the comparison?

Comment: @JackStew `( isGoodLooking && isAbleToRelocate )` A boolean already is `true` or `false`, so you don't need to compare it to see it it's equal to `true`.

Comment: @JackStew Right. If you want to compare it to `false`, use `!isGoodLooking` instead of `isGoodLooking == false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class marry {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

               int weight = 150;
               int age = 24;
              int height = 71;
              boolean isASmoker = false;
              boolean isMale = true;
              boolean isGoodLooking = true;
              boolean isAbleToRelocate = true;

        if ( ( ( weight < 160 && ( age <= 27 && age >= 22 ) ) && ( ( height < 72 ) && ( ( isASmoker == false ) && ( isMale) ) ) && ( ( isGoodLooking ) && ( isAbleToRelocate ) ) ) ) {
           System.out.println("Marry Me!");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Get Lost!");
        }
   }
}
```

Try doing it like this and it might work

If you want to check if a boolean is true you don't even have to use the `==` operator. You can just right the boolean (`isMale` for example) in the if statement. Where you went wrong originally is using the `=` operator in the if statement instead of the `==` operator but I cleaned it up even a little bit more for you.

Answer (score 0):

As EJK said `=` is an assignment operator, however you don't even need the `==` while checking `booleans` so update to match the following.

`isASmoker = false` to `!isASmoker`

and

`isMale = true` to `isMale`